# How to handle JSONP on Play! 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, jsonp, playframework-1.x

I am trying to send cross domain requests to my Play! app on Heroku from my local machine,  and thus need to use JSONP.

How do you handle JSONP on the server side with Play 1.2.4?

All help is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/JTEHkEpcmPg), which seems to be working fine.